# Handling Multiple SQL entries in NodeJs

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database

I have a code where I am handling multiple SQL entries. Following is a snippet:

```
  mysqlConnection.query(
    "INSERT INTO STUDENT_DESEASE(JEE_ROLL_NO,CHRONIC_DISEASE,DETAILS) VALUES(?,?,?)",
    [req.body.jeeroll, req.body.disease, req.body.diseasedetails],
    function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 row inserted in Student Desease");
    }
  );

  mysqlConnection.query(
    "INSERT INTO DD_DB(DD_NO,DD_DATE,DD_AMOUNT) VALUES(?,?,?)",
    [req.body.jdd, req.body.jdate, req.body.jamount],
    function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 row inserted in DD Database");
    }
  );

  mysqlConnection.query(
    "INSERT INTO DD_DB(DD_NO,DD_DATE,DD_AMOUNT) VALUES(?,?,?)",
    [req.body.idd, req.body.idate, req.body.iamount],
    function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 row inserted in DD Database");
    }
  );
```

Now for supposing my 3rd insertion entry raises an error due to any possible reasons like not valid format or already existing value and all.
Before the error, the previous 2 insertion codes have already successfully run. They have inserted their values.

So how do Handle this kind of situation?

Comment: You wrap it in a Transaction. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#transactions

Comment: @madflow thanks for your help. I guess it will resolve my issues.